# Error: system.data.rbtree'1.GetNodeByIndex(Int32 userIndex) with VB Net and Access

Tags: vb.net

I´m trying to get a value from a query with VB Net and Access database and works only for the first record, after that I´m getting this error:

> system.data.rbtree'1.GetNodeByIndex(Int32 userIndex)
>   System.Data.DataRowCollection.get:Item(Int32 index)
>   NAMEOFMYPROJECT.Form2.Button24_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>   in MYPROJECTPATH\Form2.vb:line 1048

This is my snippet:

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 2
        Try
            ConexionBD.Open()
            ComandoBD.Connection = ConexionBD
            ComandoBD.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Ventas (IdProducto, Fecha, Hora) VALUES (@IdProducto, @Fecha, @Hora)"
            ComandoBD.Parameters.Add("@IdProducto", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Form2.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
            ComandoBD.Parameters.Add("@Fecha", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = Now
            ComandoBD.Parameters.Add("@Hora", OleDbType.DBTime).Value = Now.TimeOfDay
            ComandoBD.ExecuteNonQuery()

            consulta = "SELECT CantidadDisponible FROM Productos WHERE Detalle='" & DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString & "'"
            adaptador = New OleDbDataAdapter(consulta, ConexionBD)
            registros = New DataSet
            adaptador.Fill(registros, "Productos")
            If registros.Tables("Productos").Rows.Count() <> 0 Then
                 msgbox(registros.Tables("Productos").Rows(i).Item(0)) 'HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR IS POINTING AT
            Elseif
                 msgbox("There is no available......")  'THIS MESSAGE ITS NEVER SHOWN
            End If

            ComandoBD.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        ConexionBD.Close()
    Next
```

Sorry if my question is too basic but I can´t find why is happening
PS: the database is not empty and the columns have the correct numbers

Comment: That cannot be the compleat error message. what is in the `...`?

Comment: Thanks Plutonix, I´ve updated the question, the line 1048 is where "msgbox(registros.Tables("Productos").Rows(i).Item(0))" is.

Comment: Making an assumption that your variable `i` is somehow in sync with your production table seems like a dangerous practice.  Learn to use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting issues.

Comment: Make the ID an autoincrement column and let the database assign the number for you.  Thats its job.

Comment: The Id is already an autoincrement column, "CantidadDisponible" is the available quantity of products (integer), "Detalle" is the name of the product (String)

Answer (score 1):

I found my error, I changed this:

```
msgbox(registros.Tables("Productos").Rows(i).Item(0))
```

for this:

```
msgbox(registros.Tables("Productos").Rows(0).Item(0))
```

Silly me :P

Thank you all.